# vscode HTML script Code hints how to jump to lib.dom.d.ts?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <!-- ... -->

<body>
  <script>
      console.log('1');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When `CTRL` + `left-click`, he does not jump to `lib.dom.d.ts`

[image]

I want him to jump here. Same as a `.js` file

[image]

What plug-ins should I install or how to set them up?

Comment: is mac or windows? if it is on mac try "Command + Click"

Comment: windows, '.js' file works